# D3.geo.bounds does not return bounding box?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geospatial

I am having a problem that I have traced to unexpected behavior in the `d3.geo.bounds` function.

```
var bounds = d3.geo.bounds(data);
```

For a geoJSON FeatureCollection containing only point features, a proper bounding box isn't returned: specifically, the x-values of the first and last points in the collection appear to  used instead of the min and max x-values for the group of points. This can be seen in action at http://jsbin.com/icosof/4/edit.

The bounding-box coordinates returned thus includes the min and max y-values, but not the largest and smallest x-values. Instead, these seemed to be grabbed from the first and last features in the set:

```
[[6113.30166221, -6663.98951731], [5153.32052977, -77.3529517971]]
```

Generating a bounds object by manipulating the coordinates directly

```
xvalues = [];
$.each(data.features, function(i,el){
  xvalues.push(el.geometry.coordinates[0]);
});

yvalues = [];
$.each(data.features, function(i,el){
  yvalues.push(el.geometry.coordinates[1]);
});
console.log([[Math.min.apply(null,xvalues),Math.min.apply(null,yvalues)],
[Math.max.apply(null,xvalues),Math.max.apply(null,yvalues)]]);
```

produces the desired result:

```
 [[3397.33954824, -6663.98951731], [6504.18296202, -77.3529517971]]
```

Does `d3.geo.bounds`expect a FeatureCollection sorted by x-coordinates (and if so how would I work around this), or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the confusion here is that `d3.geo.bounds` expects features to have latitude/longitude values, not x/y values. So your input is taken as `% 360`, and you won't get the max/min you expect.

You may need to convert your coordinates to lat/lon values to get this to work - left as an exercise for the reader, as I don't know what your coordinate system is.

Comment: I think D3 doesn't do any extra processing of latitudes, just longitudes.